# HackerRank Task "Mini Max Sum" solution not passing 3 of the 13 test cases, can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong

Tags: java

This is for the "Mini Max Sum" problem on HackerRank, I can't see why it doesn't have a check mark on all of the test cases. Can someone tell me where my problem lies at. The question is:

**Print two space-separated long integers denoting the respective minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by summing exactly four of the five integers. (The output can be greater than 32 bit integer.)**

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        long[] arr = new long[5];
        long total = 0, max = 0, min = 0;
        for(int arr_i=0; arr_i < 5; arr_i++){
            arr[arr_i] = in.nextLong();
            min = arr[0];
            total += arr[arr_i];
            if (arr[arr_i] > max)
                max = arr[arr_i];
            if (arr[arr_i] <= min)
                min = arr[arr_i];
        }
        System.out.println((total - max) + " " + (total - min));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should comment this line: `min = arr[0];` inside the loop as it is not required everytime in the loop.

Comment: Also set max to a very small number and min to a very big number (e.g. `Integer.MAX_VALUE`)

Comment: Actually use Long.MAX_VALUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are the initial values of both `min` and `max`.

1. `min` is being reset to the first values inside the loop, so it will probably only work if the first or the last value is the minimum one;
2. `max` starts with zero, so if all values are negative, `max` will stay at zero (instead of one of the input values).

Hints: set `min` and `max` on the first iteration (`i == 0`) or, as suggested, use Integer.MAX_VALUE and Integer.MIN_VALUE respectively as initial value (actually `long` is not needed for `min` and `max`, neither is the array)

Answer (score 2):

This also worked. Thanks!!

```
static void miniMaxSum(int[] arr) {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.sort(list); 
    long x=0, y=0;
    for(int j=0;j<(list.size()-1);j++){
            x = x + list.get(j);
            y = y + list.get(j+1);
    }
    System.out.println(x +" "+y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me in JavaScript:

```
var sum = 0;

var arry = [];

function miniMaxSum(arr) {

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {

            if (arr[j] !== arr[i]) {
                sum += arr[j];
            }

        }
        arry.push(sum);

        sum = 0;

    }


    var min = Math.min(...arry);
    var max = Math.max(...arry);

    console.log(min, max);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static void miniMaxSum(int[] arr) {
       int temp = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) { 
                if (arr[i] > arr[j]) 
                {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        long minSum = 0;
        long maxSum = 0;
      for(int i = 1; i< arr.length; i++){
         maxSum = maxSum + arr[i];
      }
      for(int i = 0; i< arr.length-1; i++){
         minSum = minSum + arr[i];
      }
      System.out.print(minSum+ " " +maxSum);
    }
```

Comment: You may need to write comments or explain your code !

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me on Python3!

```
def miniMaxSum(arr):

    total = sum(arr)
    low = total - min(arr)
    high = total - max(arr)

    print(high, low)

    return
```

Comment: This is a Java question - answers in other languages than requested shouldn't be posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

def miniMaxSum(arr):
   arr.sort()
   m = sum(arr)
   
   max_num = m - arr[-1]
   min_num = m - arr[0]
   
   print(max_num, min_num)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    miniMaxSum(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.stream.LongStream;

public class Solution {

// Complete the miniMaxSum function below.
static void miniMaxSum(int[] arr) {
long[] longs = Arrays.stream(arr).asLongStream().toArray();

Arrays.sort(longs);
long sum = LongStream.of(longs).sum();

long min = sum - longs[4];
long max = sum - longs[0];

System.out.println(min + " " + max);
}


private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = new int[5];

    String[] arrItems = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
    scanner.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int arrItem = Integer.parseInt(arrItems[i]);
        arr[i] = arrItem;
    }

    miniMaxSum(arr);

    scanner.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a hint in the question:** minimum and maximum values that can be calculated by `summing exactly four of the five integers`.

Just sort the array first, assuming the array is not sorted. Take two `for loop` because we want to keep the complexity up to O(n) i.e. Linear.

1. from `1st` index to `n - 1`. Assuming index starts from `0`. This will give you sum of all the element except the smallest element which will be the largest sum.
2. from `0th` index to `n - 2`. Assuming index starts from `0`. This will give you sum of all the element except the largest element which will be the least sum.

Let's say, Our initial numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. 
We can calculate the following sums using four of the five integers:

- If we sum everything except 1, our sum is 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 =14.
- If we sum everything except 2, our sum is 1 + 3 + 4 + 5 =13.
- If we sum everything except 3, our sum is 1 + 2 + 4 + 5 =12.
- If we sum everything except 4, our sum is 1 + 2 + 3 + 5 =11.
- If we sum everything except 5, our sum is 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 =10.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void minmaxsum(int[] ar1) {
    long a, b, c, d, e;

    a = (long) ar1[1] + (long) ar1[2] + (long) ar1[3] + (long) ar1[4];
    System.out.println(a);

    b = (long) ar1[0] + (long) ar1[2] + (long) ar1[3] + (long) ar1[4];
    System.out.println(b);

    c = (long) ar1[0] + (long) ar1[1] + (long) ar1[3] + (long) ar1[4];
    System.out.println(c);

    d = (long) ar1[0] + (long) ar1[1] + (long) ar1[2] + (long) ar1[4];
    System.out.println(d);

    e = (long) ar1[0] + (long) ar1[1] + (long) ar1[2] + (long) ar1[3];
    System.out.println(e);

    long[] df = new long[] { a, b, c, d, e };

    long max = df[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < df.length; i++) {
        if (df[i] > max) {
            max = df[i];
        }
    }

    long min = df[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < df.length; i++) {
        if (df[i] < min) {
            min = df[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(min + " " + max);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

**This answer is in PYTHON language. I am a beginner and any improvements are welcome**

`n = input().split(" ")

n=list(n)

n1 = list(map(int,n))

n2 = list(map(int,n))

n1.sort()

n1.pop()

min =0

max=0

for i in n1:

    min+=i

n2.sort()

n2.reverse()

n2.pop()

for j in n2:

    max+=j

print(min, max)`

Comment: while posting the indentation didn't come out correctly in the FOR-LOOPS, any other queries are welcome

Comment: The question is looking for an answer in Java.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I didn't see the answer should be in Java when I checked for a solution in python, I couldn't find any, so this might people needing a Python answer